# Is it safe to remove risers from stairs?

Tags: stairs

I have removed the risers from my stairs (currently halfway up) and I am wondering if they are safe? They seem sturdy enough, and since they have been like that, I have had a massive water tank removed and carried down them. But everyone keeps saying the stairs will collapse, so I am at a standstill. I do not know how to proceed.

I have been adding another tread on top of the original tread to make it meet regulations, and I like the chunky look it is giving them. I am also going to be getting them carpeted.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: By adding a second tread on top, you have changed the height of the stairs, particularly the first and last one, which will make those stairs a different height from the floor below and above. The result is a trip hazard since people expect every stair to be at the same height. The better option is to replace the treads with the same thickness but sturdier wood.

Comment: Agree with BMitch. My answer to [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/244/20) points out that some residential codes specify as little as 3/8" as the maximum rise variation.

Answer (score 4):

Risers are not a structural part of stairs. The stringers carry all the load. Risers prevent things (including heads) from slipping between the steps.

Comment: Therre are numerous designs of stairs without risers, especially in ultra modern decor, and many deck applications. Note 101's caution about things (people) sliding through